# how to disable the outer css for the specific inner id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main  with the ID "vy_accordion". Inside this , I am creating many 's dynamically by adding a new ID to each .When the specific  with the ID name "palette-selector" then outer  css should not work.

the sample code is like below

```
<div id="vy_accordion">
    <a class="divlink" href="#palette-selector">palette-selector</a>
    <div id="palette-selector" class="settingDiv" style="display: inline;">
       Some text
</div>
```

The following is the css for the above html code:

```
#vy_accordion div {
    background: white;
    display: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

In this code the property display:none should not work, when the id of the inner  is "palette-selector". how to disable display:none for the  with the id "palette-selector" ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `:not()` operator

```
#vy_accordion div:not(#palette-selector)
```

See more about this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot%28%29

Answer (score 1):

:not operator is the way to go like Marcos said.

You can also overwrite your css for #palette-selector like:

```
#palette-selector {
    background: red;
    display: block; /*this will show your div again*/
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

If you keep having problems overwriting use !important after each style, but I will try to avoid that.